# find target in tree, delete whole tree if target not found

Tags: search, recursion, tree, logic

This is more of a logic problem I'm having a hard time figuring out, I'll post psuedo code, please let me know if anything is unclear.

I'm trying to write a function that will search for multiple instances of a target in an N-array tree (each node has 0 to N children).

- If it finds 1 or more instances, it prints them all.
- If it finds no instances of the target, the whole tree must be deleted

I'm trying to solve this recursively, this is what I have:

```
bool foo(node){
    bool found = false
    if node.value = target:
        print target
        return true
    else:
        return false

    for child in node.children:
        found = found or foo(child)
    if not found:
        *run deletion process*
}
```

The problem with this is the very first if statement:

```
if node.value = target:
        print target
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

As soon as it finds the first instance of the target, it returns and stops running. But I want it to find and print ALL instances. But doing this recursively, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to order the code.

Comment: Both code paths in your `if` statement return.  The code below that is therefore unreachable, and never executes.

Comment: I understand, this is exactly the problem I'm having. But I *need* those return statements in the `if` block for recursion to work as I see it.

Comment: How is the code below that ever going to execute if you return from the function before it can execute?

Comment: I understand this. But I can't do the loop before the base case either. Basically, I'm asking whether recursion is the right technique here.

Comment: The base case has to return if the base case condition is is fulfilled.  If the base condition is not fulfilled, it has to fall through to the recursive case.  Have a look at [Fibonnaci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845154/how-does-the-the-fibonacci-recursive-function-work) for a good example of this.