# Fibonacci Recursive Function in js how it works?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I found this function in another question but i don't really understand how it works.

```
function fibonacci(n) {
       return n < 1 ? 0
            : n <= 2 ? 1
            : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }

    console.log(fibonacci(4));
    //fibonacci secuence
```

Comment: Do you understand Recursion? Take a piece of paper out with a pen.  Set n=4 and follow the code by hand.  If you can't figure it out from there then comment here and I will show you

Comment: Exactly what don't you understand about it? Please be more specific.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845154/how-does-the-the-fibonacci-recursive-function-work but I agree with RSon best to take out a pen and paper and go through the algorithm yourself

Comment: what is the question

Comment: The function is summing the numbers generated for the ternary operators?

Comment: i saw that recursive functions are a bit slow in comparison with a code like this function Fib(n) {
 var a = 0;
 var b = 1;
 var c = 0;
 
 while (a < n) {
  console.log(a + "");
  c = a;
  a = b;
  b = a + c;
 }
}

Fib(10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's not too though i think! According to me..Let me assume that u don't know about Fibonacci series. So Fibonacci series is Look like 0,1,1,2,3,5,8...
as 1=1+0, 2=1+1 ,3=2+1, 5=3+2; means every next no is a sum of 2 previous numbers.
Now lets talk about the code :
`Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2)`statements return the sum of 2 previous numbers if no is greater than 1 and 2. as a example if `Fibonacci(4);` is call then is call again`Fibonacci(3)+Fibonacci(2);` which call again 
`Fibonacci(3)=(Fibonacci(2)+Fibonacci(1)=1+0=return "1";`. And 
`Fibonacci(2)="1";`then result is=1+1=2. Now look at index 4 on series(line 2 above) its 2 on series 0,1,1,"2".
Hope You Get Your answer..Thanks

Comment: Thanks i understood the code!, what a incredible community is in this website and so inteligent people. God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

`function fibonacci(n) {}` is one of the way of writing function in javascript. This is called `function Declaration`.One of the advantage of declaring in this way is you can call the same function when there is recursion,mean in the function body you can call the function again using the name that is being done here `fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);` where `fibonacci` is the function name.

The following is a syntax for [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

Which mean is if condition is evaluated to true then `expr1` will be evaluated & if false `expr2` will be evaluated.

The ternary operator can be nested(not recommended as it increase function complexity)

```
n < 1 ? 0 : n <= 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
```

The above expression is nested ternary operator ,for simplicity of understanding it can be divided in two part ,part-1 `n < 1 ? 0` ,part-2 `: n <= 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)`.Part-2 is nested ternary operation.

According to part-1 if n is less than 1, set it to 0 else(second part) if n is less than equal to 2 set it to 1, else again recall the same function by using the name of the function(fibonacci)

Comment: Thanks a lot I think i expressed bad about asking of my doubts, i never though you'll asnwer me so fast wow you're awesome guys!