# What is recursion in python?

Tags: python, recursion

I am having a tough time understanding the concept of recursion in python and would like to understand it as it it a very important topic

tried understanding the concept on youtube and other online websites, expected to learn recursion,but i could not grasp the content properly

Comment: Recursion, generally, is the act of a function calling itself until some sort of end state is reached

Comment: I think the main thing is to distinguish function and "function invocation". Such invocation consists of the function itself, the position of execution in the function (what is the next thing to execute in the function) and the values of parameters and local variables. Function invocations are independent from each other. Calling a function (from same function or other) creates a new invocation.

Comment: I think a good example is the fibonacci series, [you can find an explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845154/how-does-the-fibonacci-recursive-function-work).

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693819/understanding-recursion-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Recursion means that a function calls itself.

Small example: This function calls itself while counting one up each time it does. If it reaches 10 we stop it or else it calls itself infinitely and runs into an error.

```
def recursiveFuntion(input):

    # print input value
    print(f'{input=}')

    # stop condition
    if input == 10:
        return
    # recursive call
    else:
        recursiveFuntion(input+1)

# call recursive function
recursiveFuntion(1)
```

Comment: Using `input` as the name of one of your variables is a pretty bad idea. You're overwriting the built-in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function.